# Spring Boot Application Proxy Authentication 407

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, proxy

Hi I got proxy 407 authentication error in my spring boot project.I tried two scenario in these scenarios proxyHost and proxyPort values are working but username and password has no effect?Is any one face this scenario?In my local machine when I give port and host and giving no username password,it works my local user and work,but I give username and password in wrong format to see its effect?I doesnt effect.
Also in server I got 407 authentication proxy exception.How can pass proxy username and password in spring boot?thanks

I add jvm parameters but proxyuser and proxyPassword no effect

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=something -Dhttps.proxyPort=5555-Dhttps.proxyUser=xxx -Dhttps.proxyPassword=yyy
```

I also add someproxy code to myresttemplate builder but it has no effect.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .build();
        int proxyPortNum =5555;
        String proxyHost="something";

         CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPortNum), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myname", "333"));

         HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        clientBuilder.useSystemProperties();
        clientBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPortNum));
        clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());
         CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
 HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setHttpClient(client);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:-----

```
 private RestTemplate createRestTemplate() throws Exception {
        final String username = "myname";
        final String password = "333";
        final String proxyUrl = "something";
        final int port = 5555;
    
        HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, port);
       HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
BasicHeader authHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization",base64authUserPassword());
headers.add(authHeader);
RequestDefaultHeaders reqHeader = new RequestDefaultHeaders(headers);
clientBuilder.addInterceptorLast(reqHeader);
        clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).disableCookieManagement();
    
        HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

public String base64authUserPassword() {
byte[] baseencode = Base64.getEncoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
return "Basic " + new String(baseencode);
}
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: unfournately not work :(,do you have any idea and thanks for your sharing...

Comment: it should work. if possible share the TRACE  log here

Comment: hey could you please check now I have updated my code now.

Comment: My first and your second method is working problem is user right.My user has lack of right in proxy.